# CURL https download not working - Getting HTML login form downloaded

Tags: curl, https, download

I am trying to download file from SWX exchange's HTTPS link. But getting HTML Login form downloaded instead of a CSV file I am expecting. Script doesn't give me any error:

```
@rem Parameters
@rem %1 production date

if not exist %1 md %1

curl -k -u XXXXX@AAAA.com:XXXX --proxy dubproxy-anus:8080 https://secure.six-swiss-exchange.com/member_section/download/memberlists/trading_memberids.csv  > \\Data\%1\trading_memberids_%1.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSV file you are trying to access requires authentication, but not in the form of server authentication using curl's `-u` option.

They use application authentication so you will need cURL to track cookies and submit the form to log in and then request the CSV file.

Something like:

```
curl -c cookies.txt -L -d viewFrom=viewLOGIN -d cugname=onems -d grouptoken=group \
-d "usertoken=test@test.com" -d password=password \
-d "forward=/onems/member_section/download/memberlists/trading_memberids.csv" \
-d actionSUBMIT=Submit \
https://secure.six-swiss-exchange.com/member_section/login-user
```

Hope that helps.